# Convert recursive lists to dynamic data.frame in R

Tags: r, recursion, dataframe, nested-lists

I need to build a function that traverses lists and sublists recursively and then convert to data.frame. Let's say I have a list like that

```
from <- list(id="12345678", name="Gabriele")
message <- "The quick fox"
comments <- list(list(name="Mickey", comment="Hello world!"), list(name="Donald", message="World...hello!"))

big.list <- list(from, message, comments)
```

I need to convert it in the form of a data.frame with this schema

```
from_id, from_name, message, comments_name, comments_message
```

(in other words, flattening the sublists)

The problem is that I don't know in advance which fields I have in the lists and which I've not (for example, some posts may miss the comments section altogether).

Comment: `b` is not defined and also there is a typo with `}`

Comment: fixex the above example, tnx

Comment: May be `do.call(cbind,lapply(big.list, function(x) as.data.frame.list(unlist(x))))`

Comment: Tnx for your comment, but it gives me an error about non unique row.names...

Comment: It worked in the example data without any errors, but in your original data, there may be duplicate names, please do provide a small example that shows the error

Comment: that's really weird...I've applied to big.list as defined in the example, copypasting from it. This is the error i got:  Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("name", "comment",  : 
  'row.names' duplicate non sono permesse In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘name’

Comment: I am using `R 3.2.0` in case there are version difference

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick trial. If `big.list` has names, they can be taken as column names.

The inner `do.call()` flattens the sub-list while the outer one converts into a data frame.

```
lst1 <- list(from = list(id="12345678", name="Gabriele"),message = "The quick fox",
             comments = list(list(name="Mickey", comment="Hello world!"),
                            list(name="Donald", message="World...hello!")))
lst2 <- list(from = list(id="12345678", name="Gabriele"),message = "The quick fox",
             comments = list(list(name="Mickey", comment="Hello world!")))
lst3 <- list(from = list(id="12345678", name="Gabriele"),message = "The quick fox")

df1 <- do.call(data.frame, do.call(c, lst1))
df2 <- do.call(data.frame, do.call(c, lst2))
df3 <- do.call(data.frame, do.call(c, lst3))

df1
#from.id from.name       message comments1.name comments1.comment comments2.name comments2.message
#1 12345678  Gabriele The quick fox         Mickey      Hello world!         Donald    World...hello!

df2
#from.id from.name       message comments.name comments.comment
#1 12345678  Gabriele The quick fox        Mickey     Hello world!

df3
#from.id from.name       message
#1 12345678  Gabriele The quick fox
```

@ Gabriele B

Below is clumsy but working solution. Others may post a better one.

```
from <- list(id="12345678", name="Gabriele")
message <- "The quick fox"
comments <- list(list(name="Mickey", comment="Hello world!"), list(name="Donald", message="World...hello!"))
big.list <- list(from = from, message = message, comments = comments)
big.list1 <- list(from = from, message = message)

join <- function(lst) {
  if(length(lst$comments) < 1) {
    bnd <- data.frame(id = unlist(lst$from)[1], name = unlist(lst$from)[2], lst$message)
    bnd$cmt.name <- "na"
    bnd$comment <- "na"
    bnd
  } else {
    bnd <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(lst$comments), function(x) {
      id <- unlist(lst$from)[1]
      name <- unlist(lst$from)[2]
      data.frame(id = id, name = name, lst$message)
    }))
    bnd <- cbind(bnd, do.call(rbind, lst$comments))
    names(bnd) <- c("id", "name", "message", "cmt.name", "comment")
    bnd
  }  
}

join(big.list)
#id     name       message cmt.name        comment
#id  12345678 Gabriele The quick fox   Mickey   Hello world!
#id1 12345678 Gabriele The quick fox   Donald World...hello!

join(big.list1)
#id     name   lst.message cmt.name comment
#id 12345678 Gabriele The quick fox       na      na
```

Comment: tnx for your solution! It works, but it's not 100% what I need (I updated the question to clarify), as it trasposes the comments. The idea is to perform a kind of 'cross join' between the main list and the 'comments' (ie if a post has 3 comments, I will end up having 3 rows for that post